# regex for input mask - comma separated list of up to three characters per item

Tags: javascript, regex, input-mask

I have an `input` field, which I want to limit as follows:

1. The input will be a comma-separated list
2. Each string in the list must be limited to 1..3 characters
3. The list can have as many items as the user wants

some examples:

`1,4,6a,16b`
`1`
`abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx,yzz`

I have found the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2x8y1dhL/ which provides a starting point for creating an input mask, but it assumes a fixed number of items in the list, and a fixed length of each input.

What I want is the following logic:

- after the user inputs the third character in a row that isn't a comma, a comma is automatically inserted

Comment: provide what you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I have worked on the jsfiddle you have found](https://jsfiddle.net/no75cqjg/). Some notes:

- You have not specified valid/invalid characters, but the examples given seem to suggest "alpha-numeric plus comma"
- Consecutive commas are allowed as it's not specified otherwise.

The meat of the matter are the two functions `createMask` and `destroyMask`:

```
function createMask(string){
    return string.replace(/(\w{3})(?!,)(.+)$/g,"$1,$2");
}

function destroyMask(string){
    return string.replace(/[^0-9A-Z,]/ig,'');
}
```

---

**Update 1:**  Pasting input that is longer than six characters - i.e. needs to be split more than once - turned out to be problematic with the original answer. An explicit loop is needed as the `g` modifier does not help with that regex. Here's the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5o2zcxtm/):

```
function createMask(string){
  let s = string;
  let t;
  do {
    t = s;
    s = s.replace(/(\w{3})(?!,)(.+)$/,"$1,$2");    
  } while (s !== t)
  return s;
}
```

---

**Update 2:** However, we can get away without an explicit loop with this alternative regex that only uses a single capture - [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukj5bovs/):

```
function createMask(string){
    return string.replace(/(\w{3})(?!,|$)/g,"$1,");
}
```

Comment: This will match: `123456` - not limited to 3 characters.

Comment: Pasting `123456` will actually be split fine by this fiddle. Pasting longer strings, though, will not. I've updated the answer to allow pasting of longer inputs.

Comment: When 'repairing' `1234`, should it be `123,4` or `12,34` or `1,234` - you can't know.

Comment: You can, because the question says `after the user inputs the third character in a row that isn't a comma, a comma is automatically inserted`. So it is `123,4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat optional repetitions of 3 word characters followed by a comma and then match 3 word characters asserting a word char to the right.

```
^(?:\w{3},)*\w{3}(?=\w)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yAhIKY/1) | [Forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnx83v7a/)

In the replacement use the full match `$&` followed by a comma.

```js
$("input[name='masknumber']").on("input", function(){
  let n = destroyMask(this.value);
    this.setAttribute("data-normalized", n);
  this.value = createMask(n);
})

function createMask(string){
    return string.replace(/^(?:\w{3},)*\w{3}(?=\w)/g,"$&,");
}

function destroyMask(string){
    return string.replace(/[^0-9A-Z,]/ig,'');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="masknumber" data-normalized="" size=64>
```

Or [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e35u8jkb/) with a variant with 2 capture groups.